# Row GridView like url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Как представить строку GridView единой ссылкой?

**UPD:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"  OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" PageSize="2" CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id">
            <ItemTemplate>
 ...
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No result for search!
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

**UPD2:** Кто-то знает решение именно на asp.net?

Comment: Что конкретно вы хотите? По нажатию на строчку переходить по ссылке? Дайте код вашего GridView

Comment: Да, этого и хочу. Сейчас реализовал через HyperLinkFiled, но это не не то.

Comment: А где темплэйт? я знаю как через JS это сделать в MVC, механизм схожий должен быть

Comment: обновил вопрос, там есть. или нужно с .cs файла?
я не умею работать с JS и могу тупо код готовый только вставить.

Comment: ну тогда примерно так `<div class="link-class" data-id="идентификатор элемента записи">собственно тут то что в роу</div>` код JS: `<script type="text/javascript"> $('.link-class').on('click', function(){ $(location).attr('href','Ваш урл куда надо идти'+$(this).data('id'); })</script>`

Comment: примерно я думаю, что можно ловить контрол нажатия мышкой по конкретной ячейки, доставать всю связанную с этой ячейкой строку, брать из нее Row.Cell[0] - значение первого столбца и передавать его как querystring дальше через Server.Transfer или Response.Redirect. Но я хз как словить значение ячейки по которой кликнули и как достать связанную с этим строку. Хотя я уверен, что теоретически такая задача решаема. Нашел в интернете пару решений, но там совсем дичь)

Comment: в моем примере не обязательно должен быть div, вполне возможен и tr

Comment: Попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30488/discussion-between-disguiseperceptron-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Главная страница:**

```
   <columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="details.aspx?Id={0}" DataTextField="Id"  ShowHeader="False" DataTextFormatString="Click for details" />
   </columns>
```

**Дополнительная страница:**

gridview/detailsview с запросом

```
"Select * from `table` WHERE [id] = @id"
```

При конфигурации sql-запроса жмем источник QueryString(строка запроса сверху url).

Лучшее решение, что я нашел.

**Дополнительная литература:**

[тыц](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/base/level7/7_5.php)